# Unable to catch and handle spring custom events in java

Tags: java, spring, events, event-handling

I am trying to set up a custom spring event publisher and listener. 
The flow of the process seems to be working fine, I can see the prints before the event publishes,  however, my event listeners do not catch the event.
my main class is:

```
public class TestClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            testEvents();
        }

        private static void testEvents() throws InterruptedException {
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext eventPublisherContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EventListenerConfig.class);
            CustomSpringEventPublisher eventPublisher = eventPublisherContext.getBean(CustomSpringEventPublisher.class);
            List<CustomSpringEventListener> listenersList = new ArrayList<CustomSpringEventListener>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                listenersList.add(new CustomSpringEventListener("LR" + (i + 1)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);

                LocalDateTime now  = LocalDateTime.now();
                eventPublisher.doStuffAndPublishAnEvent("new event " + now.format(Formats.isolong));
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my custom event class:

```
public class CustomSpringEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private String message;

    public CustomSpringEvent(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

here is my custom event publisher class:

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventPublisher {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public void doStuffAndPublishAnEvent(final String message) {
        System.out.println("Publishing custom event --> " + message);
        this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new CustomSpringEvent(this, message));
    }

}
```

here is my custom event listener class:

```
public class CustomSpringEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomSpringEvent> {
    private String name;

    public CustomSpringEventListener(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomSpringEvent event) {
        System.out.println(name + " received spring custom event - " + event.getMessage());
    }

}
```

here is my event listener config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"some.local.directory.testCases"})
public class EventListenerConfig {
}
```

What am I missing here? How can I get my listener class to recognize the published event and handle it?
I saw some examples in which the listener class has the `@Component`, but when I tried to add it I got an error from spring:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`, also I don't see any reason why would the listener class have this annotation in this case.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call event listeners, Spring needs to know the listener class and have it into its `applicationContext`, under what is called a **Bean**.

You do need to annotate your class with `@Component`. But when you do so, you get an error. Let's clarify this.

## Quick overview of Spring

Having a class annotated with `@Component` will indicate to Spring it needs to "manage" the class himself. By managing, it includes creating all the "dependencies" first, and then calling the "constructor". Let's call this the **dependency tree**. Once Spring gets to the bottom of it, it can start climbing back up and creating the object and its way back to the top.

### Dependencies management

Spring knows your classe's dependencies by analyzing the constructor, setter or attributes annotated by `@Autowired`. Note that if your class has only one constructor, Spring automatically scans it to know about dependencies, even if there is not `@Autowired` at the top of it.

In your case, for `CustomSpringEventListener`, you have one constructor taking in parameter a String. If we build the dependency tree of your `CustomSpringEventListener`, we get something like that :

```
CustomSpringEventListener ---> String
```

So when Spring tries to create your `CustomSpringEventListener`, it will look for a bean of type `String`, because, your code is saying : If you ever want to create an object `CustomSpringEventListener`, you need to give a name which is a String.
But you do not have a bean of type String in your code I guess.

## The solution

In a first time, annotate your class `CustomSpringEventListener` with `@Component` and remove your attribute and the constructor.

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomSpringEvent> {

    @Override
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomSpringEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received spring custom event - " + event.getMessage());
    }

}
```

In a second time, find a different way to have a name in your class if you really need it.

#### Listener with attributes

Let's say you need a more sophisticated Listener, like one using a `ServiceA`. You can do the following :

```
@Service
public class ServiceA { ... }
```

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomSpringEvent> {
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    public CustomSpringEventListener(ServiceA serviceA) {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

}
```

#### Same listener with a name

You can combine `@Configuration` class to create many times the same Listener. 
Let's use your first Listener, with the `name` attribute.

```
public class CustomSpringEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomSpringEvent> {
    private String name;

    public CustomSpringEventListener(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomSpringEvent event) {
        System.out.println(name + " received spring custom event - " + event.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Without the `@Component` annotation, what you can do is using a `@Configuration` class to instantiate your Listener:

```
@Configuration
public ListenerConfig {

    public CustomSpringEventListener listenerA() {
        return new CustomSpringEventListener("listenerA");
    }

    public CustomSpringEventListener listenerB() {
        return new CustomSpringEventListener("listenerB");
    }

    public CustomSpringEventListener listenerC() {
        return new CustomSpringEventListener("listenerC");
    }

    ...
}
```

You can mix Spring configuration to do whatever configuration you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that sort of work. Now I can see the print from the listener, but I was expecting to see 5 prints because I generate 5 listeners, and instead, I see only one. Does that mean I can Have only one listener for the same event? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, does it mean that my listener class can't have any attributes what so ever? I can't take a complicated class and make it implement or extend ApplicationListener?

Comment: Of course you can have many Listeners, just create different classes and annotate them by `@Component`. You can also have listener class with attributes, but make sure that Spring knows about the dependencies your class needs. Like, if your Listener needs a Service class, make sure the Service class is a bean. And Spring will autowire it for you. But in your case, Spring didn't know anything about a bean of type `String`.

Comment: Makes sense. But why only one lister is handling the event instead of all five of them? I still do not get this part.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it is okay for you.